# iPod Touch 4: Use as phone/text?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I have an Android phone and an iPod Touch.  The camera on the iPod Touch is front-facing and much better than the one on the Android, and with so much communication among my social groups moving towards photo/video I feel kind of left out because my phone sucks at this.  Unfortunately, I can't just switch from my current phone to an iPhone, but really I already have a Touch so ideally there would be some way for me to just get it to act as much like an iPhone as possible.  How would I do this, and is there a way to do it without being reliant on WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

Your iPod is very similar to an iPhone. However, there is one major difference - it does not have the ability to send and receive cellular. Any kind of video chatting with an iPod requires WiFi. You may be able to communicate with Bluetooth also; however, what I have read it can only go between to Apple products and has very little range.